# Return an object with a specific variable

Tags: c++

So if I have this:

```
class Object {
    public:
        Object(const int id);
        ~Object();

    private:
        int o_id;
};
```

How do I return an Object with a specific o_id (let's say 5)?

Comment: `Object foo(){ return Object{5}; }`?

Answer (score 3):

Your Question is a bit Confusing. In C++  function can return objects either by value or by reference. When an object is returned by value from a function.

This can may help you :

```
class Object
 {
  public:
    int value() const
    {
      return m_value;
    }

    void setValue( int i )
    {
      m_value = i;
    }

  private:
    int m_value;
 };
```

Comment: Ok let me rephrase. I am making a script for a multiplayer game. When the player connects, I want to make a Player object for him, using his playerid which is provided by the game. Now let's say I have an in-game command /getname playerid ; which should get the name of the playerid, which is stored in the object.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the definition of your constructor initializes `o_id` like so

```
Object::Object(const int id) : o_id(id) {}
```

Then you just call the constructor with the appropriate id.

```
Object an_object(5); // o_id is set to 5
```